# Below which matrix density does it become advantageous to use sparse matrices instead of dense matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

My understanding/ some assumptions:

- You can **in theory** use a sparse matrix even when there are no non-zero items (dense)
- You can **in theory** use a dense matrix even when there are many zero items (sparse)
- Let's call density the number of non-zero items divided by number of all items in the matrix

Using a dense matrix when data is sparse, or vice versa, is probably not optimal, but I like to know below which density (ballpark figure) should one use a sparse matrix? Or below which density would you call data sparse?

Comment: Depends in part on what operations you are doing.

Comment: I have a 60,000 x 220 matrix M with 0's and 1's of which I want to take M @ M.T. 856,951 values are non-zero, which is ~6.5%. I am in doubt whether I should use dense or sparse matrices, but either way my laptop doesn't seem to be able to handle it. EDIT: which surprises me, because the resulting matrix would be roughly 3.6 GB which should fit in memory. If sparse maybe less??

Comment: EDIT2: would it help if I split the calculation into pieces??

Comment: The resulting matrix would be 15gb, not 3.6. You might be better off if you use a sparse matrix, but maybe not. Depends on structure and how many nonzeros after the multiplication.

Comment: @CJR can you explain why 15 gb? I thought 60k^2 gives 3.6 billion items each being 1 byte (dtype=np.int8)

Comment: Unless you're preallocating and feeding the array into the `out` argument it'll use the int32 or int64 (I forget which)

Comment: Don't count on matrix multiplication working with `int8`.  Where it uses fast compiled code (dense or sparse), it probably uses standard `c` numeric types, such as `float32` or `float64`.  Test alternatives with smaller dimensions with less memory issues.